# ASP.NET Core web app in C# and windows application in VB.net combination

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-core

I would like to know how to combine a VB.Net Windows application and C# ASP.NET Core web app together. I created a web app using C# because VB.net is not supported. What is the best method to do it?

Create DLL file for asp.net core and import to VB.Net is possible or not? if it is possible how to create dll file in asp.net core?

Web application and windows application are separate purpose applications. Not the same applications. The main application is a windows application. it some values create and store in SQL Server then those values represent in web application using SQL Server.

Comment: What do you mean by combine them? You want some logic from the web app in the vb.net project? If so put that logic in a class library, you do not want to bring a web app into another project as a reference.

Comment: Both are separate applications so the main application is a windows application. web application shows some values in the SQL database created in windows application.

Comment: So you want to call the web application from the (presumably) winforms application?  You need to make an HTTP call, [maybe start here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Comment: No, web application update by MS SQL server. MS SQL server database update by Windows application. Both are seperate but when windows application run web app also want to run. I think best way make dll file for asp.net and use it in VB.net project. is it posible?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: my windows application use enters some values and store in SQL server. That is windows application. My web application show in the browser by getting values in the SQL database. that is separate application. I want to run web application when windows application is run.  I think best way to do it create dll file for asp.net and use it in VB.net project. is it posible?

Comment: Web applications run on servers and typically stay running all the time. No, the best way is NOT to create a dll, it wouldn't even work. The best way is to host your web app somewhere. Like you said, they are separate.

Comment: Perhaps you should regard the database as the main application. The program and web interface are just ways of accessing the database.

Comment: what about making your VB.net app create a new process and run the "dotnet run youraspnet.dll" to either doing the edit part and listening to HTTP?

Answer (score 1):

I can see two ways:

1. Create a `.NET Standard` library with all DB operations and consume this project by both VB.NET Windows application and ASP.NET Core Web application.
2. Create a `Web API` application which will expose all DB operations as endpoints and again consume it by both apps.

Second option requires more work to do, but has better logic separation.